# Updating formview in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, formview

net.I am designing with help of data views in Visual Studio  2010.GridView and DetailsView run with no issues.In FormView as I am trying to develop a edit template with following code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
        onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [student]"
        UpdateCommand="Update student set Id=@Id, Name=@Name, City=@City, Marks=@Marks where Id=@Id" >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am getting an error as follows:

`'ASP.default_aspx'` does not contain a definition for `'SqlDataSource1_Selecting'` and no extension method `'SqlDataSource1_Selecting'` accepting a first argument of type `'ASP.default_aspx'` could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I solve it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you defined

```
  onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"
```

but probably in the code behind there is no function with the right signature

Answer (score 1):

## As the error clearly states, you don't have any SqlDataSource1_Selecting method (for the onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" event handler)

**Error:**

> ASP.default_aspx' does not contain a definition for
> 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' and   no extension method
> 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' accepting a first argument of type
> 'ASP.default_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive
> or an assembly  reference?)

**Your Code**

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1"
                    runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString1 %>" 
                    onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [student]"
                    UpdateCommand="Update student set Id=@Id,
                                                      Name=@Name, 
                                                      City=@City, 
                                                      Marks=@Marks
                                   where Id=@Id" >
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

**Problem With the code**

```
 onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"  there is no extension for this available
```

**Updated:**

Your Web.config defines an OleDb connection string (for the OleDb engine) that uses the SQL Server OleDb provider to connect to SQL Server through OleDb.

Your code then passes that connection string to a SqlConnection, which connects directly to SQL Server using the SQL native client and uses a completely different connection string.

You should change Web.config to use System.Data.SqlClient and its connection string format. (this is more efficient than OleDb)